# How to allow optional outermost parenthesis?

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

I am writing a parser for certain expressions. I want to allow parentheses to be optional at the outermost level. My current parser looks like this:

```
class MyParser extends JavaTokenParsers {

  def expr = andExpr | orExpr | term
  def andExpr = "(" ~> expr ~ "and" ~ expr <~ ")"
  def orExpr = "(" ~> expr ~ "or" ~ expr <~ ")"
  def term = """[a-z]""".r
}
```

As it is, this parser accepts only fully parenthesized expressions, such as:

```
val s1 = "(a and b)"
val s2 = "((a and b) or c)"
val s3 = "((a and b) or (c and d))"
```

My question is, is there any modification I can make to this parser in order for the outermost parenthesis to be optional? I would like to accept the string:

```
val s4 = "(a and b) or (c and d)"
```

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose the 2nd `andExpr` was supposed to be `orExpr`?

Comment: Scala's combinator parsers don't have any kind of operator precedence notation, so you have to stratify you grammar to handle operator precedence. Once you do that, adding a production at the highest precedence level that derives a parenthesized instance of the top-level expression production.

Comment: how can "def orExpr = "(" ~> term ~ "or" ~ term <~ ")"" parse "((a and b) or c)"?

Comment: True, my example is wrong. I'll fix it so it's defined recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  // the complete parser can be either a parenthesisless "andExpr" or parenthesisless          
  // "orExpr " or "expr"
  def complete = andExpr | orExpr | expr
  def expr = parenthesis | term
  // moved the parenthesis from the andExpr and orExpr so I dont have to create
  // an extra parenthesisless andExpr and orExpr
  def parenthesis = "(" ~> (andExpr | orExpr) <~ ")"
  def andExpr = expr ~ "and" ~ expr
  def orExpr = expr ~ "or" ~ expr
  def term = """[a-z]""".r
}
```

Comment: It'd be better if you explained what you changed.

Comment: @Siphor, Thanks for this. I actually had the initial parser wrongly written, as you pointed out. I have fixed it. Does this change your answer?

Comment: In the ``def parenthesis`` line, does the ``|`` operator have precedence over the ``~>`` operator? That is, is it equivalent to ``"(" ~> (andExpr | orExpr) <~ ")"``?

Comment: No it does not. Forgot about that, will fix it.